# Is this code correct for execution across multiple processors?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

Is the code below the correct way to execute **func** in parallel across multiple processors (`dfA_Train` and `dfB_Train` are lists of Pandas DataFrames)?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

def func(dfA, dfB, param):
  L = []
  ...
  return L #L is a list of dictionaries

if __name__ == "__main__":
   dictList = []
   for param in paramGrid:
      with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
         rslts = pool.starmap(func, zip(dfA_Train, dfB_Train, itertools.repeat(param)))
      rslts = [item for subList in rslts for item in subList if item != []]
     _ = [dictList.append(item) for item in rslts]
   results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictList) if dictList else None
```

It doesn't seem to be running in more than 1 proc - there is no speedup between single proc and multiple procs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `multiprocessing.dummy` just invokes multiple threads under hoods as per the doc below. When we go for threads, obviously a single process is invoked where each thread is controlled by the global interpreter lock. `multiprocessing.Pool()` would be the right candidate here to achieve parallelism here. Unlike threads, the `Pool` object allocates separate process for each task. For instance, consider the below example.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker_function(arg_1, arg_2):
    print('do some work with arg_1 and arg_2')

work = (["A", 5], ["B", 2], ["C", 1], ["D", 3])
proc_pool = Pool(<desired no. of processes>)          # create a multi processing Pool
proc_pool.map(worker_function, work)                  # start parallel work
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I do have ```from multiprocessing import Pool``` and it doesn't seem to using 8 procs